# Readable first few lines in Questions or Answers

Tags: discussion

When browsing *Questions* or *Answers* on math.SE, is it possible to read the first portion of the text directly on $\TeX$ with mathematical symbols? I mean without clicking on the title/header?

EDIT: Sorry, it improved later on. Mostly it is a *very slow* browser I used and posted it too soon, I wish to delete the post now.

Comment: I must admit that I really don't know what you mean by "read[ing] the first portion of the text... on TEX...."

Comment: I have a sneaky feeling that this is a dupe of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13835/excerpts-in-search-results-breaks-mathjax-fragments and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/formatting-in-the-search-results-page-breaks-when-the-query-contains-certain-ter

Comment: @WillieWong, +1 for "sneaky feelings" lol